# ORA-02070: database does not support in this context

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have a query like

```
INSERT INTO sid_rem@dev_db
(sid)
select sid from v$session
```

Now, when i execute this query i get 
    `ORA-02070: database does not support in this context`

This error happens only when I insert data from v$session into some remote db. Its working fine for any other table.

Anyone know why this issue and any workaround for this?

Comment: It should be noted that SO's whitespace removal is removing additional spaces between "database" and "does" and "support" and "in" implying that there is _something_ that is not supported that Oracle doesn't want to talk about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works using `gv$session` instead of `v$session`:

```
INSERT INTO sid_rem@dev_db(sid)
select sid from gv$session;
```

gv$ views are global views, that is, they are not restricted to one node(instance), but see the entire database(RAC). v$ views are subviews of gv$.

Searching on the internet I found this has something to do with distributed transactions.

[Thread on ora-code.com](http://ora-02070.ora-code.com/msg/72556.html)

Comment: nice find (you might want to make it a bit clearer that you are using **gv$**, not **v$**. I took me a while to see that....)

Comment: `v$session` is essentially a view of `gv$session` but limited to your current instance, which ought to be the same in a non-RAC environment. The limitation is done with a `where inst_id = USERENV('Instance')` clause, as in the thread you linked to, and it is that which causes the ORA-02070.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I've added a short explantion of gv$ views.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but might still be useful.  I've found this error occurs when trying to select from system views across a database link where the system view contains columns of type LONG.  If the query can be reworded to avoid the LONG columns these joins will work fine.

Example:

```
SELECT dc_prod.*
  FROM dba_constraints@prod_link dc_prod
  INNER JOIN dba_constraints dc_dev
    ON (dc_dev.CONSTRAINT_NAME = dc_prod.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
```

will fail with an ORA-02070 due to accessing the LONG column `SEARCH_CONDITION`, but

```
SELECT dc_prod.*
  FROM (SELECT OWNER,
               CONSTRAINT_NAME,
               CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
               TABLE_NAME,
               -- SEARCH_CONDITION,
               R_OWNER,
               R_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
               DELETE_RULE,
               STATUS,
               DEFERRABLE,
               DEFERRED,
               VALIDATED,
               GENERATED,
               BAD,
               RELY,
               LAST_CHANGE,
               INDEX_OWNER,
               INDEX_NAME,
               INVALID,
               VIEW_RELATED
          FROM dba_constraints@prod_link) dc_prod
  INNER JOIN (SELECT OWNER,
                     CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                     CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
                     TABLE_NAME,
                     -- SEARCH_CONDITION,
                     R_OWNER,
                     R_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                     DELETE_RULE,
                     STATUS,
                     DEFERRABLE,
                     DEFERRED,
                     VALIDATED,
                     GENERATED,
                     BAD,
                     RELY,
                     LAST_CHANGE,
                     INDEX_OWNER,
                     INDEX_NAME,
                     INVALID,
                     VIEW_RELATED
          FROM dba_constraints) dc_dev
    ON (dc_dev.CONSTRAINT_NAME = dc_prod.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
```

works fine because the LONG column `SEARCH_CONDITION` from DBA_CONSTRAINTS is not accessed.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is happening, it's probably in the documentation somewhere but my Oracle-Docs-Fu seems to have deserted me today.

One possible work-around is to use a [global temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633)

```
SQL> create table tmp_ben ( sid number );

Table created.

SQL> connect schema/pw@db2
Connected.
SQL> create table tmp_ben ( sid number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tmp_ben@db1 select sid from v$session;
insert into tmp_ben@db1 select sid from v$session
                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02070: database  does not support  in this context

SQL> create global temporary table tmp_ben_test ( sid number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tmp_ben_test select sid from v$session;

73 rows created.

SQL> insert into tmp_ben@db1 select * from tmp_ben_test;

73 rows created.
```