# ORA-02070: database does not support in this context

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to insert data from a VIEW in one DB to a table in another DB.

```
insert into schema.dummy_table@LINK 
SELECT v1.coulmn1, v1.cloumn2, v1.clolumn5, v1.cloumn7, v1.column3
 FROM user.view1 v1, user.view2 v2
        WHERE v1.column8 = v2.column1;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get

```
ORA-02070: database  does not support  in this context
```

Does that mean, this is not permitted on views?

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: The error message is missing the specifics. It sould be more like "database XE does not support  USERENV in this context"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name schema.dummy has below columns:

`column1 NUMBER (15) NOT NULL,
column2 VARCHAR2 (240) NOT NULL,
column3 VARCHAR2 (255),
column4 NUMBER (15),
column5 NUMBER (15),
column6 DATE,
column7 DATE,
column8 NUMBER (10),
column9 VARCHAR2 (40),
column10 VARCHAR2 (40),
column11 VARCHAR2 (240),
column12 VARCHAR2 (255);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: And my Insert goes exactly like this: `insert into schema.dummy@LINK SELECT v1.request_id, v1.program_name, v1.parameters, v1.program_id, v1.parent_id, v1.start_date, v1.completion_date, (v1.completion_date - v1.start_date ) * 24 * 60 runtime, v1.status, v1.user,v2.user_value, v1.logname FROM user.view1 v1, user.view2 where v1.user_id=v2.user_id;`

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns in the views though @zephyrus. For instance, you cannot do this with a LOB.

Comment: Datatype of dummy table : `REQUEST_ID NUMBER (15) USER_CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME VARCHAR2 (240 Byte) ARGUMENT_TEXT VARCHAR2 (255 Byte) CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_ID NUMBER (15) PARENT_REQUEST_ID NUMBER (15) ACTUAL_START_DATE DATE ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE DATE RUNTIME NUMBER (10) PROGRAM_STATUS VARCHAR2 (40 Byte) REQUESTOR VARCHAR2 (140 Byte) RESPONSIBILITY_NAME VARCHAR2 (140 Byte) LOGFILE_NAME VARCHAR2 (255 Byte)`

Comment: Datatype of the columns in view: `REQUEST_ID NUMBER (15)
USER_CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME VARCHAR2 (240 Byte)
ARGUMENT_TEXT VARCHAR2 (240 Byte)
CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_ID NUMBER (15)
PARENT_REQUEST_ID NUMBER (15)
ACTUAL_START_DATE DATE
ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE DATE
STATUS_CODE VARCHAR2 (1 Byte)
REQUESTOR VARCHAR2 (100 Byte)
RESPONSIBILITY_NAME VARCHAR2 (100 Byte)
LOGFILE_NAME VARCHAR2 (255 Byte)
`

Comment: Query I use: `INSERT INTO allen.dummy@prod_to_dev SELECT fcrfv.request_id, fcrfv.user_concurrent_program_name, fcrfv.argument_text, fcrfv.concurrent_program_id, fcrfv.parent_request_id, fcrfv.actual_start_date, fcrfv.actual_completion_date, (fcrfv.actual_completion_date - fcrfv.actual_start_date) * 24 * 60, fcrfv.status_code, fcrfv.requestor, frv.responsibilty_name, fcrfv.logfile_name FROM apps.fnd_conc_requests_form_v fcrfv, apps.fnd_responsibility_vl frv WHERE fcrfv.responsibility_id = frv.responsibility_id;`

Answer (score 2):

Based on names of the columns I guess that `user.view1` or `user.view2` selects data from one of system views like `v$session`.
Try to use `gv$` views instead of `v$` views.

This case already explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14153972/232279) on StackOverflow.

Source of such behavior is that `where inst_id = USERENV('Instance')` used in almost all `v$`-type views

Comment: This is the query: `INSERT INTO allen.dummy@prod_to_dev
   SELECT fcrfv.request_id, fcrfv.user_concurrent_program_name,
          fcrfv.argument_text, fcrfv.concurrent_program_id,
          fcrfv.parent_request_id, fcrfv.actual_start_date,
          fcrfv.actual_completion_date,
          (fcrfv.actual_completion_date - fcrfv.actual_start_date) * 24 * 60,
          fcrfv.status_code, fcrfv.requestor, frv.responsibilty_name,
          fcrfv.logfile_name
     FROM apps.fnd_conc_requests_form_v fcrfv, apps.fnd_responsibility_vl frv
    WHERE fcrfv.responsibility_id = frv.responsibility_id;`

Comment: Is `apps.fnd_conc_requests_form_v` and `apps.fnd_responsibility_vl`  a views? If so, it must be traced down to tables and system views level to determine if any `v$` views involved in this query.

Comment: Tracing back to the tables actually helped. So this doesn't work on views but I still do not understand why. Anyway, issue reolved.

Comment: The same problem may be caused by the call of sys_context, e.g. in the view DBA_OBJECTS, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448918/ora-02070-database-does-not-support-in-this-context-via-db-link/34451106#34451106)