# ORA-02070: database does not support in this context Via DB LINK

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I have a View and want to insert this via DB Link. But it's give error "ORA-02070: database does not support in this context". How can I solve this error ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW V_TEST
(
   OBJECT_ID,
   SEQUENCE,
   SCHEMA_NAME,
   OBJECT_NAME,
   OBJECT_TYPE_NAME,
   LINE,
   POSITION,
   ERROR_MESSAGE,
   CREATE_DATE
)
AS
     SELECT dbaObjects.OBJECT_ID,
            dbaErrors.SEQUENCE,
            dbaErrors.OWNER AS SCHEMA_NAME,
            dbaErrors.NAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
            dbaErrors.TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE_NAME,
            dbaErrors.LINE,
            dbaErrors.POSITION,
            dbaErrors.TEXT AS ERROR_MESSAGE,
            SYSDATE AS CREATE_DATE
       FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS dbaObjects, SYS.DBA_ERRORS dbaErrors
      WHERE     dbaObjects.OWNER = dbaErrors.OWNER
            AND dbaObjects.OBJECT_NAME = dbaErrors.NAME
            AND dbaObjects.OBJECT_TYPE = dbaErrors.TYPE
            AND dbaObjects.OWNER != 'SYS'
            AND dbaObjects.OWNER = 'HELLO'
            AND dbaObjects.STATUS = 'INVALID'
            AND dbaErrors.TEXT != 'PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored'
            AND dbaErrors.TEXT != 'PL/SQL: Statement ignored'
   ORDER BY dbaErrors.OWNER,
            dbaErrors.NAME,
            dbaErrors.TYPE,
            dbaErrors.SEQUENCE;
```

View and Remote Table Types are same

[image]

Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO HELLO.T_INVALID_OBJECT_2@VADA (OBJECT_ID,
                                                    SEQUENCE,
                                                    SCHEMA_NAME,
                                                    OBJECT_TYPE_NAME,
                                                    OBJECT_NAME,
                                                    LINE,
                                                    POSITION,
                                                    ERROR_MESSAGE,
                                                    CREATE_DATE)
   SELECT V.OBJECT_ID,
          V.SEQUENCE,
          V.SCHEMA_NAME,
          V.OBJECT_TYPE_NAME,
          V.OBJECT_NAME,
          V.LINE,
          V.POSITION,
          V.ERROR_MESSAGE,
          V.CREATE_DATE
     FROM V_TEST V;
```

It's give error Insert Statement :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem has somehow to do with the views used in your view (`DBA_SOURCES` and `DBA_ERRORS`). See the discussion on the same variation with `V$SESSION` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984203/ora-02070-database-does-not-support-in-this-context) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153972/ora-02070-database-does-not-support-in-this-context).

Unfortunately I don't see a same simple solution as for V$SESSION (as proposed in the link above) and it seems to me that the problem is cause by the call of `sys_context` in the (nested view of the) view `DBA_OBJECTS`. So the *propper* solution is either in writing your own version of `DBA_OBJECTS` without using `sys_context` / `USERENV` or in creation a local copy of this data (e.g. in GTT)

Anyway there are two workaround:

**1)  revert the insert**, i.e. connect to the remote DB ans insert from a view via DB LINK.

```
insert into t_demo
select * from v_demo@demo;
```

if connection to remote DB is not an option, you may

**2) alternatively  define a PROCEDURE on the remote DB** and call it from the local DB

```
-- ON REMOTE DB
create procedure ins_remote   
AS
   BEGIN
    insert into t_demo
    select * from v_demo@demo;        
   END;
/
-- plus grants for execute


-- ON LOCAL DB
begin 
   ins_remote@demo;
end;
/
```